# Get DropDownListFor selected value in multiple model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I create multiple model

```
public class MultipleModel
{
    public Photo Photo { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }
}
```

for two different models:

```
public class Room
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NumberRoom { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photo { get; set; }
    }
public class Photo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PhotoName { get; set; }
        public int Roomid { get; set; }
        public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
    }
```

On click `Submit` in my view i want upload image to the folder with the name from DropDownListFor selected item ( for example /images/2/, where 2=id from `DropDownListFor`) and add to database. How i can correctly send selected item from DropDownListFor using Html.BeginForm?
My view:

```
@using Hotel.BusinessObject
@model MultipleModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRoomImg", "Admin",
        FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = Model.Room.Id}))
{
    <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.Room.Id, ViewBag.roomlist as SelectList, "Select Room")</div>

    <input type="file" name="img" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
}
```

And my controller, where `Room.Id` in `formCollection` is always=0 and `int? id` not works and return `NULL`

```
        public ActionResult AddRoomImg()
        {
            ViewBag.roomlist = new SelectList(db.Room, "Id", "NumberRoom");
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddRoomImg(FormCollection formCollection, int? id)
        {
            foreach (string item in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[item] as HttpPostedFileBase;
                if (file.ContentLength == 0)
                    continue;
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    ImageUpload imageUpload = new ImageUpload { Width = 600 };

                    ImageResult imageResult = imageUpload.RenameUploadFile(file);
                    if (imageResult.Success)
                    {
                        //TODO: write the filename to the db 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Error = imageResult.ErrorMessage;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: (1) In the `BeginForm()` method, `new { id = Model.Room.Id }` is adding a html attribute - its unclear what your trying to do with this (2) Your POST method signature should be `public ActionResult AddRoomImg(MultipleModel model, HttpPostedFileBase img)` and `model.Room.Id` will contain the selected value and `img` will contain the file. (3) Your `<input type="file" ..>` is not multiple, so why are you using a `foreach` loop? (4) Use a view model containing only those properties you need to display/edit in the view

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRoomImg(MultipleModel model, HttpPostedFileBase img)
{
     //your code here
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRoomImg(MultipleModel model)
{
     var image = Request.Files(0); //access your images

     //rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to clarify anything, I understand what OP is trying to do and I gave him the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is about getting selected value from dropdownListFor into the `MultipleModel`, first of all you should update your function parameters.

use `MultipleModel model` to get the form data into model and`HttpPostedFileBase img` instead of `FormCollection formCollection` to get the image file as object. try the following way.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRoomImg(MultipleModel model, HttpPostedFileBase img)
{
    // To get the selected value from dropdownListFor
    var selectedRoomId = model.Room.Id;

    // do what you want to do with img object
    // you will get img.name in the file object that you can rename
}
```